# Spring oauth default token caching?

Tags: spring-security, jwt, spring-oauth2

I haven't been able to find the documentation for Spring-managed tokens, and how to cache them. The below code triggers an auth call to get the token EVERY time I call the remove service.

I'm using Spring OAuth with default configuration as follows:

```
@Bean(name="serviceRestTemplate")
public RestTemplate serviceRestTemplate(
    @Value("${authUri}") String authUri,
    @Value("${username}") String username,
    @Value("${password}") String password,
    @Value("${readTimeout}") int readTimeout,
    @Value("${connectTimeout}") int connectTimeout) {

ClientCredentialsResourceDetails details = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
details.setAccessTokenUri(authUri);
    details.setClientId(username);
    details.setClientSecret(password);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(details, new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(new DefaultAccessTokenRequest());
}
```

My questions are:

- What is the default behavior? / Is there any kind of caching with the above?
- Can I enable token caching through Spring?

Comment: Did you reuse the `restTemplate` or did you create it again for every request?

Comment: I reuse it. (It's created as a `@Bean` in the ApplicationContext)

Comment: If you reuse `restTemplate`, the token should be cached, see [OAuth 2 Developers Guide](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html). What scope do you use?

Comment: I'm not actually setting a scope. Maybe that's the problem? Thanks for the guide link! The client token caching section is a bit brief, but I'll see what I can figure out.

Comment: Oh, nope, it looks like this won't work out of the box? I have to implement `ClientTokenServices` and provide it to the rest template in order for it to work?

Comment: Could you check, if the token is saved in `DefaultOAuth2ClientContext` after executing the first request?

Comment: This looks to be a duplicate of [OAuth2RestTemplate - Client Side Caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53418928) which, though was asked later, received a good answer.