# OAuth2RestTemplate - Client Side Caching

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I see the below restTemplate being used for fetching OAuth token. I don't see any explicit call to cache the token in my application. However I see the same token value being returned by this template. Does OAuth2RestTemplate inherently implement client side caching? If so , does it make an explicit call to the OAuth2 endpoint when the token expires?

```
@Qualifier("oauth")
@Bean
public OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate(@Qualifier("resourceDetails") ClientCredentialsResourceDetails resourceDetails) {
    return new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails);
}
```

I saw the below in the documentation -

> getAccessToken public OAuth2AccessToken getAccessToken()
>                                    throws UserRedirectRequiredException
>
> Acquire or renew an access token for the current context if necessary.
>   This method will be called automatically when a request is executed
>   (and the result is cached), but can also be called as a standalone
>   method to pre-populate the token.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it's clearly said that the token is cached in the context (DefaultOAuth2ClientContext object) created when defining a resource. however, the token is managed by calling getAccessToken(). here is what the Docs says about getAccessToken():

> Acquire or renew an access token for the current context if necessary.
>   This method will be called automatically   * when a request is
>   executed (and the result is cached), but can also be called as a
>   standalone method to   * pre-populate the token.

the token is cached until it's Expired, then it will be renewed automatically. this snippet of code from getAccessToken() describes it:

```
if (accessToken == null || accessToken.isExpired()) {
            try {
                accessToken = acquireAccessToken(context);
            }
```

About Caching mechanism, By default spring provides an in-memory caching

> DefaultOAuth2ClientContext

but you can provide your own implementation of

> OAuth2ClientContext

Comment: Thanks @slimane , that's what I saw in the documentation as mentioned in my question. Do you know how long it is cached , when it is refreshed and what happens when token expires?

Comment: @PunterVicky I included that in my answer ;)